# .focus() after reloading page with jQuery in phoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to solve an issue with a phonegap app for Android.
I have a function like this one on a dinamic page

```
$(objLid).change(
    function (e){
        //Save data for reload
        _prototype.saveFormData();
        //reload call
        reloadPage();
        //first attempt to have the focus on the right obj      
        $(objLid).focus();
    }
);
```

That's how it work:
The button have type "select-one" after the user select one of the element i save all the previous item on text field, then i call the reload function that add other field on the page.
On iOs without the .focus() call i have no problem but on Android after the reload the application automatically makes a scroll at the top of the page. I've tried:

```
$mobile.silentscroll(Y) //with Y as a given Y position
```

But it work as the focus, after the reload Android makes a scroll at the top. The same with setTimout hoping for a delayed effect but unsuccessfully:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(objLid).focus();
}, 1000 );
```

There's an hack to this annoying "scroll"?

Thanks